# mongoose update failed when i use var but success when i use constant?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i try to wirte a js script to pull an elem in a array in mongo.

// this one not work, which return "{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }"

```
db.userModel.updateOne({"_id":userId}, {"$pull" : {"draw.awardList":{oldActiveCode : oldTime}}}, function(err, res) ..
```

// this one work，

```
db.userModel.updateOne({"_id":userId}, {"$pull" : {"draw.awardList":{"1000812001401": 1553503004448}}}, function(err, res)
```

// but when i compare then, it seems equal

```
console.log("+++",("1000812001401" === oldActiveCode), (oldTime === 1553503004448))
```

output : +++ true true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{oldActiveCode : oldTime}` and `{"1000812001401": 1553503004448}` are not the same. The former sets `oldActiveCode` property, and the latter sets `1000812001401` property.

If the property should be `1000812001401`, it should be computed property, `{[oldActiveCode] : oldTime}`.